# how to pass string with character '&' in url in php

Tags: php, get

I am developing program in `PHP`. Now i want to pass the whole string with '&' character using `$_GET`. But I'm facing some problem like it cuts the string from character '&' 
i have use code as below

```
$customer="Mahindra & Mahindra PVT.LTD."
<a href="main.php?cust=". $customer."">Procceed</a>
```

and in second page use code:
new veriable is declared and then passes url veriable in it and print variable.

```
$c=$_GET['customer'];
echo $c;
```

its output is "`Hahindra`", but I want to get whole string.

Comment: urlencode function might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $customer="Mahindra & Mahindra PVT.LTD.";
echo '<a href="main.php?cust="'.urlencode($customer).'">Procceed</a>'; ?>
```